# How to show unapproved comments only for comment's author (not registered) in wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I get comments with

```
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id'=>get_the_ID(), 
    'order'=>'ASC',
));
```

I show comments with checking `$comment->comment_approved` in the loop.
but I want to show unapproved comments to the guy who send the comment.

my solution is checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $comment->comment_agent` in a loop of all comments (approved or not), but I'm not sure, is it enough?! or must check something else values?

Comment: I don't get it! Why do you want to check `comment_approved`, but you also want the unapproved comments??

Comment: I want to show approved comment for all visitors, except for who have a unapproved comment show that unapproved comment; [like this](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8274404368/sample.png). I would be happy for any clue or mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the best solution that I found:

```
// geting comments of post
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id'=>get_the_ID(), 
    'order'=>'ASC',
));  

foreach($comments as $comment){ 
    // if unapproved comment is not commented by this user continue...
    if(!$comment->comment_approved && $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $comment->comment_agent){
        continue;
    } 
    // if unapproved comment is commented by this user show the message.
    if(!$comment->comment_approved && $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $comment->comment_agent){ 
        echo "Your comment is awaiting moderation";
    } 
    // show the comment 
    echo $comment->comment_content . '<br>';    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id'=>get_the_ID(), 
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'status' => 'approve',
    'include_unapproved' => array(is_user_logged_in() ? get_current_user_id() : wp_get_unapproved_comment_author_email())
));
```

I think it is a mistake to use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` header. This header only identifies the requesters browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

So that check will have the effect of displaying the unapproved comment to any user using the same browser as the comment's author.

Instead, `get_comments()` supports an 'include_unapproved' query argument to include unapproved comments for the user associated with the request.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

In the example above, `wp_get_unapproved_comment_author_email()` will look for request parameters such as 'moderation-hash' and user cookies to attempt to determine whether a request was issued by the same user that posted the comment. It should be noted that users may refuse cookies or switch devices, and the monitored request parameters will only be set for the one request immediately after posting a comment, so this function may not always work.

It should also be noted that the 'identity' returned by `wp_get_unapproved_comment_author_email()` is not authenticated or secured in any way. Users can easily use the "Save my name, email, and website" cookie to assert that they are posting on behalf of an email address that they do not own, and will then be shown unapproved comments that also asserted that email address. For this reason I recommend sites require users to be registered and logged in in order to comment.

That said, checks based on `wp_get_unapproved_comment_author_email()` will serve the purpose of hiding unauthorised comments from users not deliberatly trying to compromise the system, and this is the technique used in the main wordpress comment loop: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/

Comment: The problem is if the theme author disables the email field from the comment form. In that case 'wp_get_unapproved_comment_author_email()' is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add the below code wherever you need the comment

```
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id'=> get_the_ID(), 
    'order'=>'ASC',
));

if ( is_user_has_unapproved ( $comments, get_current_user_id() ) ) {
    echo "Your comment is awaiting moderation";
} else {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo $comment->comment_content."<br>";
    }
}
```

Add this in your `functions.php`

```
function is_user_has_unapproved ( $comments, $user_id ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        if ( $comment->user_id == $user_id ) {
            if ( $comment->comment_approved == "0" ) {
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $i != 0 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: but in this solution; if post have any unapproved comment, nobody can see any comment (even approved comments). because `get_current_user_id()` return `0` for all normal visitors (unregistered). look this is my solution, is it all right?    `foreach($comments as $comment){ 
  if(!$comment->comment_approved && $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $comment->comment_agent){
   continue;
  } 
  if(!$comment->comment_approved && $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $comment->comment_agent){
   echo 'Your comment is awaiting moderation';
  }
    echo $comment->comment_content; 
  }`

Comment: because wordpress save user_agent in comments table in comment_agent  column  for each comment. and we can comparison it to the current visitor user_agent. my question is: don't we need more checks like IP or something?! or is my solution totally ok?! and after all thank you for your patient.

Comment: So there are anonymous ( Unregistered users ) comments? Have you tried my above code? `get_current_user_id()` return `0` I agree, but that won't be a problem. Just let me know the output of the above code!!

Comment: I try your code, It's not what I want. your code show `Your comment is awaiting moderation` for all unregistered visitors. I want show is for the user who left the comment. actually if the visitor left a comment (even in last visits) can see his unapproved comment/comments and the other's approved comments. so my code is a loop of all comment, then I check if comment is unapproved and comment_agent was equal with current user agent then I show it for user. I think almost all wordpress themes have this feature, but they use simply default template or somethings.